# SupportFragment not shown on device

Tags: android, android-support-library

Currently I am learning about android support library and I want to add SupportFragments to my test-application. The fragments I've implemented are working on my 2.3.3 emulator and my tablet Samsung Note with 4.0.4, but not on my Samsung S5 with 5.x.

The NavigationDrawer implemented is working very well, the corresponding methods are all called. When I open the drawer, click on the 2nd menu item the method for replacing the fragments is called.

I hope I've added all the important code parts.

Logcat Output:

```
    11-03 14:04:26.356 4861-4861/incentivelabs.supportlibtest E/Zygote: MountEmulatedStorage()
11-03 14:04:26.356 4861-4861/incentivelabs.supportlibtest E/Zygote: v2
11-03 14:04:26.356 4861-4861/incentivelabs.supportlibtest I/SELinux: Function: selinux_compare_spd_ram, SPD-policy is existed. and_ver=SEPF_SM-G901F_5.0.2 ver=27
11-03 14:04:26.356 4861-4861/incentivelabs.supportlibtest I/SELinux: Function: selinux_compare_spd_ram , priority [1] , priority version is VE=SEPF_SM-G901F_5.0.2_0027
11-03 14:04:26.356 4861-4861/incentivelabs.supportlibtest E/SELinux: [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: default sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
11-03 14:04:26.356 4861-4861/incentivelabs.supportlibtest I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
11-03 14:04:26.356 4861-4861/incentivelabs.supportlibtest I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD checking this for 10292
11-03 14:04:26.356 4861-4861/incentivelabs.supportlibtest I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD not a persona
11-03 14:04:26.376 4861-4861/incentivelabs.supportlibtest D/TimaKeyStoreProvider: TimaSignature is unavailable
11-03 14:04:26.386 4861-4861/incentivelabs.supportlibtest D/ActivityThread: Added TimaKeyStore provider
11-03 14:04:26.566 4861-4878/incentivelabs.supportlibtest I/GMPM: App measurement is starting up
11-03 14:04:26.566 4861-4878/incentivelabs.supportlibtest E/GMPM: getGoogleAppId failed with status: 10
11-03 14:04:26.576 4861-4878/incentivelabs.supportlibtest E/GMPM: Uploading is not possible. App measurement disabled
11-03 14:04:26.626 4861-4861/incentivelabs.supportlibtest D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* installDecor mIsFloating : false
11-03 14:04:26.626 4861-4861/incentivelabs.supportlibtest D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* installDecor flags : -2139029248
11-03 14:04:26.656 4861-4861/incentivelabs.supportlibtest D/AbsListView: Get MotionRecognitionManager
11-03 14:04:26.686 4861-4861/incentivelabs.supportlibtest D/API: RUNNING NEW DEVICE
11-03 14:04:26.716 4861-4897/incentivelabs.supportlibtest D/OpenGLRenderer: Render dirty regions requested: true
11-03 14:04:26.726 4861-4861/incentivelabs.supportlibtest D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* isFloatingMenuEnabled mFloatingMenuBtn : null
11-03 14:04:26.726 4861-4861/incentivelabs.supportlibtest D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* isFloatingMenuEnabled return false
11-03 14:04:26.766 4861-4897/incentivelabs.supportlibtest I/Adreno: EGLInit: QTI Build: 02/03/15, b606245, I0829b9e471, 20150203_LA_BF_2_1_AU139
11-03 14:04:26.776 4861-4897/incentivelabs.supportlibtest I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
11-03 14:04:26.786 4861-4897/incentivelabs.supportlibtest D/OpenGLRenderer: Get maximum texture size. GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE is 16384
11-03 14:04:26.786 4861-4897/incentivelabs.supportlibtest D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
11-03 14:04:26.936 4861-4861/incentivelabs.supportlibtest I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@3cea95f1 time:553865839
```

MainActivity (contains the fragments):

```
package incentivelabs.supportlibtest;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements  BlankFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
                    PlusOneFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
                    NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener
{


    Toolbar mToolbar;
    DrawerLayout mDrawer;
    NavigationView mNavViewer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mDrawer = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawerlayout);
        mNavViewer = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigationViewer);
        mNavViewer.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

        android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if(actionBar != null)
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        mToolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mDrawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            }
        });

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            Log.d("API", "RUNNING NEW DEVICE");
        }else{
            Log.d("API", "RUNNING OLD DEVICE");
        }

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.nav_contentframe, new BlankFragment()).commit();

    }


    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
        Log.d("Menu", "Button pressed");
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.file:
                Snackbar.make(mDrawer,"Context Menu button pressed", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction("Action", null).show();
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    private void switchFragement(Fragment target){
        Log.d("Fragment", "Switching fragment");
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
        // and add the transaction to the back stack so the user can navigate back
        transaction.replace(R.id.nav_contentframe, target);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);

        // Commit the transaction
        transaction.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
        menuItem.setCheckable(true);
        switch(menuItem.getItemId()){
            case R.id.navigation_item_1:
                switchFragement(new BlankFragment());
                break;

            case R.id.navigation_item_2:
                switchFragement(new PlusOneFragment());
                break;
        }
        mDrawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

The layout XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawerlayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">



    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/nav_contentframe"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize" />




    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:id="@+id/navigationViewer"
        android:divider="@color/colorAccent"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/menu_header_layout"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The BlankFrament (the other one looks nearly the same)

```
package incentivelabs.supportlibtest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link BlankFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link BlankFragment#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class BlankFragment extends Fragment {


    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment BlankFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static BlankFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        BlankFragment fragment = new BlankFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public BlankFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p/>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem was the layout xml file. 
The AppBarLayout was occupying the whole screen, so the FrameLayout for the fragments was not visible (I guess outside the screen at the bottom).
I placed the FrameLayout inside the AppBarLayout (I dont know if this is a very good practice) and now everything is working fine on every device I've tested on.

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/nav_contentframe"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="13"
            android:background="@android:color/background_light"
            />
```